# MySQL running on Amazon EBS EC2 performs a lot faster than Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

Currently, I have MySQL running on EBS EC2 us-east-1c. I wanted to try Amazon RDS so created an instance running on "us-east-1b", but the response from the RDS is really slow. It takes about few seconds (2sec to 3sec) to get response from RDS whereas response from MySQL EBS EC is in 100ms.

I was just wondering if this is expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs RDS using EBS as the file storage, so you should be getting the same level of performance.  You can try increasing the size of the RDS storage so that the data is striped across multiple EBS volumes to increase performance.

One of the downsides of moving things to the cloud is you loose the ability to control a lot of this stuff.